# Retrieving selected data from three different listviews in contextmenuitemselected

Tags: android, listview, android-contextmenu

I am new to android,
I have created an activity which has tab in it. And each tab contains one list view, now in context menu I am giving option to delete and edit the List view contents. But i am not able to get the identity of the selected item in list view. List view is populated from 3 different tables in database.

By directly giving the list view name i can get the data but i have 3 different list view.

This is What i did

```
birthdaylv = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.bdaylist);
anniversarylv = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.anniversarylistview);
otherslv = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.otherslistview);

registerForContextMenu(birthdaylv);
registerForContextMenu(anniversarylv);
registerForContextMenu(otherslv);


try{
    SimpleAdapter adapter = new SimpleAdapter(this, data, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_2, new String[] {"name", "date"}, new int[] {android.R.id.text1, android.R.id.text2});
    birthdaylv.setAdapter(adapter);
   }
catch(NullPointerException e){}
try{
    SimpleAdapter adapter2 = new SimpleAdapter(this, data1, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_2, new String[] {"name", "date"}, new int[] {android.R.id.text1, android.R.id.text2});
    anniversarylv.setAdapter(adapter2);
   }
catch(NullPointerException e){}
try{
    SimpleAdapter adapter3 = new SimpleAdapter(this, data2, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_2, new String[] {"name", "date"}, new int[] {android.R.id.text1, android.R.id.text2});
    otherslv.setAdapter(adapter3);
    }
catch(NullPointerException e){}


@Override  
public void onCreateContextMenu(ContextMenu menu, View v,ContextMenuInfo menuInfo) {  
    super.onCreateContextMenu(menu, v, menuInfo);  
    menu.setHeaderTitle("What you want to do?");  
    menu.add(0, v.getId(), 0, "Edit Date");
    menu.add(0, v.getId(), 0, "Delete Event");  
}

@Override
public boolean onContextItemSelected(MenuItem item) {

    final AdapterContextMenuInfo info = (AdapterContextMenuInfo) item.getMenuInfo();
position = (int) info.id;
Log.d("Event", "List position "+position);
if(item.getTitle()=="Edit Date"){
        DatePickerDialog dpd = new DatePickerDialog(this, new OnDateSetListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDateSet(DatePicker view, int year, int monthOfYear,int dayOfMonth) {

        }
    }, year, month, dayofmonth);
    dpd.show();
    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Editing", 1000).show();
    }
    else if(item.getTitle()=="Delete Event"){
        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Deleting", 1000).show();
    }
    else {
        return false;
        }
return true;
}
```

If Edit Date is selected i want for which list view item, i.e. I want the selected data from the list view. 
Please help.

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: Hi, and welcome to Stack Overflow. In order to help you you can you please show us what you have tried, the relevant code and the **specific** issues you are having. Read up on [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and have a look at the [help centre](http://stackoverflow.com/help) on here. Then [edit](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/25161482/edit) your question and give all the necessary details.

Comment: Found **answer** myself.. Created three setOnClickContextMenu instead of registering to one contextmenu...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best practice here is to stick to the [MVC Pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Model%E2%80%93view%E2%80%93controller). In your case you add a `OnItemSelectedListener` to every of you ListViews and store the selected value (not the index of the list) in your MVC-Model, afterwards you can the access the selected data from everywhere in you application via the model.